# Remove NAs and drag other values up

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I've transposed a matrix and now I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   Placebo  High  Medium     Low
      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.0400  NA    NA      NA     
 2  0.04    NA    NA      NA     
 3  0.0200  NA    NA      NA     
 4  0.03    NA    NA      NA     
 5 -0.00500 NA    NA      NA     
 6  0.0300  NA    NA      NA     
 7 NA       -0.04 NA      NA     
 8 NA       NA     0.0100 NA     
 9 NA       NA    NA       0.0100
10 NA       NA    NA       0.04
```

I would like to remove the NAs so every value goes up, and I get something like:

```
   Placebo  High  Medium     Low
      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.0400  -0.04   0.0100  0.0100
 2  0.04                    0.04 
 3  0.0200  
 4  0.03     
 5 -0.00500 
 6  0.0300
```

It doens't matter if the columns do not have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a dataframe that *looks like* your desired output. However, it's impractical to have such kind of dataframe.

The "empty" cells are filled with "", therefore, the column type will be character instead of numeric.

```
do.call(data.frame, 
        lapply(
          sapply(df, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), 
          function(y) append(y, rep("", max(apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))) - length(y))))
        )

  Placebo  High Medium  Low
1    0.04 -0.04   0.01 0.01
2    0.04              0.04
3    0.02                  
4    0.03                  
5  -0.005                  
6    0.03
```

Replacing "" with `NA` might be better, which preserves the column types as numeric.

```
do.call(data.frame, 
        lapply(
          sapply(df, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), 
          function(y) append(y, rep(NA, max(apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))) - length(y))))
        )

  Placebo  High Medium  Low
1   0.040 -0.04   0.01 0.01
2   0.040    NA     NA 0.04
3   0.020    NA     NA   NA
4   0.030    NA     NA   NA
5  -0.005    NA     NA   NA
6   0.030    NA     NA   NA
```

---

Here's a potentially faster method that only uses one `lapply` instead of `lapply` + `sapply`.

```
do.call(data.frame,
        setNames(lapply(1:ncol(df), function(x)
          append(
            df[, x][!is.na(df[, x])],
            rep(NA, max(apply(df, 2, function(x)
              sum(!is.na(x)))) - length(df[, x][!is.na(df[, x])]))
          )),
          colnames(df)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't end up with a data frame because you have columns of different lengths. You will need to end up with a list, by doing something like:

```r
df  <- read.table(text = "Index Placebo  High  Medium     Low
 1  0.0400  NA    NA      NA     
 2  0.04    NA    NA      NA     
 3  0.0200  NA    NA      NA     
 4  0.03    NA    NA      NA     
 5 -0.00500 NA    NA      NA     
 6  0.0300  NA    NA      NA     
 7 NA       -0.04 NA      NA     
 8 NA       NA     0.0100 NA     
 9 NA       NA    NA       0.0100
10 NA       NA    NA       0.04 ", header = TRUE) 
df["Index"]  <- NULL

lapply(df, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])

# $Placebo
# [1]  0.040  0.040  0.020  0.030 -0.005  0.030

# $High
# [1] -0.04

# $Medium
# [1] 0.01

# $Low
# [1] 0.01 0.04
```